# Need to unblind Game of Thrones Conquest so I can transfer my game account

Tags: facebook, game-center

GoTC is currently bound to FB and Game Center... using iPad Pro 12.9”, iPhone 6s Plus and also have iMac but don’t play this on it.

GoTC is the only game I’ve seen that doesn’t let you unblind within the game, so there should be a workaround, right? The new user wants me to bind it to her Game Center account so she can take it over. I just need to unbind it from my Game Center account first!

Comment: Did you ask the developer of the app how to do this?  Maybe they have a support page?

Comment: Yes, I opened a ticket and their initial response was that this feature is not offered at this time. Other games allow you to unbind and bind at will. This is why I was hoping that the game could be unbound via a workaround in iOS